# Batch convert svg to pdf page size

Tags: pdf, svg, converters, inkscape

I have a number of svg files created with inkscape that contain text in non-standard fonts. As far as I understand, in order to have them printed I need to convert the text to paths. It seems that if I just use

```
convert input.svg output.pdf
```

the text is automatically converted to paths. Is this correct?

However my problem is with the page size. The input svg have a page size of A5, landscape. However the converted pdf seem to be cut on the right and bottom of the image by about 5% of the image width/height.

Why is that? How do I fix it?

Comment: On your first question: you *want* the text converted to paths and they *are* converted to paths. So why the question? ("Converting text to paths" is not an absolute requirement for printing, but your print provider may ask it anyway.)

Comment: @usr2564301: Well it is not a real question. However I noticed that different converters handle this differently. Apparently "convert" (from imagemagick) does convert them to paths, while `rsvg-convert` does not. I just want to make sure that whatever method is proposed does two things: 1) converts text to paths and 2) fixes my problems with the output size.

Comment: How do you check the output size? What is the result in millimeters?

Comment: @usr2564301: For the pdf, in  evince, in "properties" it tells me "10.33 × 7.28 inch". It is obviously too small, because the image in the original fills almost all of an a5 page, but in the converted pdf a part of the image is missing/cropped.

Comment: Imagemagick is a raster image processor. It converts svg to raster pixels, then encloses that raster image in pdf vector shell. So you lose your vector paths, since they become pixels. I do not think Imagemagick is the tool for this job, if you want to keep vector paths in your PDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you have Inkscape on your system, ImageMagick `convert` actually delegates the PDF export to Inkscape. You can use it directly on the command line as

```
inkscape -zA output.pdf input.svg
```

Quote from [man](https://inkscape.org/sk/doc/inkscape-man.html):

> Used fonts are subset and embedded.

There are some options to manipulate the export area. `-C` explicitely sets the page area, `-D` the drawing bounding box.

You could even preserve the SVG format by using

```
inkscape -Tl output.svg input.svg
```

which would convert text to path.

Lastely, since you have to batch-process multiple files, you should open a shell with

```
inkscape --shell
```

and process all files in one go. Otherwise, startup time of inkscape would be 1-3 seconds for every file. Something like:

```
ls -1 *.svg | awk -F. \
    '{ print "-AC " $1 ".pdf" $0 }
    END { print "quit" }' | \
    inkscape --shell
```

Comment: Thanks. Conversion with inkscape worked as expected, both for conversion to pdf and to png. Still don't understand why imagemagick "convert" and "rsvg-convert" had a problem with the size.

Comment: Just an hunch: if width/height were not stated as px but in, cm or other real-world sizes, they would have been on a Inkscape-configured conversion factor, not the systemwide one.

Comment: This might very well be it. I specified width/height in mm in the svg. How would I match the conversion factors in that case?

Comment: I think there is no "reset" in inkscape - you'll have to put Settings -> Interface -> Zoom correction to what the system setting amounts to (sorry, can't tell a shell command to get that off the top of my hat.)